# How do i find domain of $\tan(z)$ that is differentiable??

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How do i find domain of $\tan(z)$ that is differentiable??

I haven seen forums where people showed until this part 
$$
\tan(z) = \frac{\tan(x)+i\tanh(y)}{1−i\tan(x)\tanh(y)} , $$
where $z$ is complex.

what should I do next or is that any other method??

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Do you want the maximal connected open set containing a given point such that tan remains holomorphic there? Or do you actually want everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$ where tan is holomorphic? The latter is where cos is nonzero, which is everywhere except the obvious points on the real axis.

Comment: @Ian I just want to make it into a form such that I can apply the Cauchy-Riemann equation or if possible, other methods to prove tan(z) to be differentiable

Answer (score 1):

For complex differentiability, you need to check [the Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).

You need to find the real part $U$ and the imaginary part $V$:

$$\mathrm f(x+\mathrm iy) = U(x,y) + \mathrm i V(x,y)$$

Then you need to check that **both** $U_x = V_y$ **and** $U_y = -V_x$.

In [***a post last year***](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1732112/38495), the real and imaginary parts were shown to be
\begin{eqnarray*}
U(x,y) &=& \frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x + \cosh 2y} \\ \\
V(x,y) &=& \frac{\sinh 2y}{\cos 2x + \cosh 2y}
\end{eqnarray*}

You now want to check where **both** $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial y}$ **and** $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}$.

You also need $\tan z$ to be well-defined for it to be differentiable, i.e. $\cos 2x + \cosh 2y \neq 0$.

Comment: thanks every appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to invoke the CR equations. For real $x$ the $\tan$ is formally defined by
$$\tan x:={\sin x\over\cos x}\ ,\tag{1}$$ and this does give indeed a real value, unless $\cos x=0$. The latter is the case when $x$ is an odd multiple of ${\pi\over 2}$. The natural extension of $\tan$ to ${\mathbb C}$ therefore is
$$\tan z:={\sin z\over\cos z}=-i\>{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\over e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}\ ,$$
and this coincides with $(1)$ when $z\in{\mathbb R}$. The differentiation rules for analytic functions then allow to conclude that $\tan$ is analytic in all points $z\in{\mathbb C}$ where  $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\ne0$.
Now
$$e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=-e^{-iz}\bigl(e^{i(2z-\pi)}-1\bigr)\ .$$
Here the RHS is $=0$ iff
$$i(2z-\pi)=2k\pi i,\quad k\in{\mathbb Z}\ ,$$
or $$z=k\pi+{\pi\over2},\quad k\in{\mathbb Z}\ .$$
It follows that the extended $\tan$ is complex differentiable at all points of ${\mathbb C}$ minus the already known singular points on the real axis.

Comment: hi  @Christian Blatter thanks for helping!